# Sending a system exclusive message using CoreMIDI

Tags: swift, macos, midi, coremidi

I'm working on a MacOS app where I'm utilizing MIDI. What I'd like to do is send s SysEx message to a MIDI device. Now, I've done this once in Java, but never in Swift.

And since the `coremidi` library is almost totally new to me, i have no idea how this would work. What I've figured out so far is that I have to compose a `MIDISysexSendRequest`, and I've come this far:

```
let SysEx = MIDISysexSendRequest(destination: self.endpointRef, data: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, bytesToSend: 8, complete: complete, reserved: (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8), completionProc: completionProc, completionRefCon: nil)
```

In this, there are a few things that confuse me:

- In what way am i supposed to compose the `data` variable? I know what bytes i want to send, just not how to format this for Swift
- What is `reserved` supposed to be?

I couldn't find any examples or reference on these that i could use. Could someone help me/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reserved** means you can't use it, as in: "reserved for internal use"

```
struct MIDISysexSendRequest
{
    MIDIEndpointRef     destination;
    const Byte *        data;
    UInt32              bytesToSend;
    Boolean             complete;
    Byte                reserved[3];
    MIDICompletionProc  completionProc;
    void * __nullable   completionRefCon;
};

/*!
    @struct         MIDISysexSendRequest
    @abstract       A request to transmit a system-exclusive event.

    @field          destination
                        The endpoint to which the event is to be sent.
    @field          data
                        Initially, a pointer to the sys-ex event to be sent.
                        MIDISendSysex will advance this pointer as bytes are
                        sent.
    @field          bytesToSend
                        Initially, the number of bytes to be sent.  MIDISendSysex
                        will decrement this counter as bytes are sent.
    @field          complete
                        The client may set this to true at any time to abort
                        transmission.  The implementation sets this to true when
                        all bytes have been sent.
    @field          completionProc
                        Called when all bytes have been sent, or after the client
                        has set complete to true.
    @field          completionRefCon
                        Passed as a refCon to completionProc.

    @discussion
        This represents a request to send a single system-exclusive MIDI event to
        a MIDI destination asynchronously.
*/
```

Notice how the reserved variable doesn't even show up in the header.

A quick google shows many projects written in swift that use MIDI. Browse through some of these to see working examples.

The first one I looked at seemed perfect for seeing how things are done. It even has quite a few .java files, so it might be easier for you to see how it relates to swift (or how to connect them).

Take a look here: [MIDI in Swift](https://github.com/adamnemecek/WebMIDIKit)

In the CoreMIDI framework there is a file called "MIDIServices.h" (finder will find it for you).  It has a LOT of information regarding MIDI.

Best of luck!!

Comment: This is a complete answer to both questions. Could the persons who downvoted it please explain to me what is lacking? I was trying to avoid writing the code for the OP. As in "teaching one to fish".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me out lots. I filled in everything except for the `reserved` option, since I'm really not sure what I'm supposed to fill in there, with a signature of `(UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)` Also, to the person who downvoted and didn't give any correspondence or an answer, you're a twatt

Comment: thanks for the support - . To get the listing above I put my cursor on the command and did a command-click to bring up the header file, since hovering didn't give me information on that reserved variable...

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but even within the `MIDIServices.h` file, there is no documentation on the `reserved` option, and I don't know what type of data it wants from me, seeing how the signature just says `<#(UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)#>`. Could you help me out by telling me what bytes i should fill in here? thanks

Comment: Yes.  I'm still looking for that myself. I haven't found an example on my mac, I'll have to google for a bit. I'll let you know if I come up with it. I'd try with 0s for now, since it is reserved, maybe what you pass in is ignored? Not sure yet.

Comment: Little more info, whenever I try either `0's` or just some random bytes, I get the following: `Contextual type for closure argument expects 1 argument, which cannot be ignored`

Comment: Did you try just one 0 Without parens? I'm seeing this in headers: "UInt8     reserved1; // MUST be set to zero"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146072/discussion-between-wesley-li-and-mozahler).